# SUMIFS + VLOOKUP tricky use in excel

Tags: excel, row, vlookup, sumifs

I've got two files with excel sheets

The first one consists of 2 columns

**First one is ARTICLE (with article numbers), second one is QUANTITY (with product quantity)**

Second file consists of two sheets

**First sheet contains two columns is CODE (code numbers), second one is QUANTITY (with product quantity)**

**Second sheet consists of two columns CODE and ARTICLE**

The thing is one code, for instance "2111", can contain up to 5-10 different articles

My goal is to find the right articles in the first file depending on the code in the second one and calculate the quantity in the second one.

THANK YOU SO MUCH for any insights!

Comment: Would help understanding your data structure and desired outcome with some sample data, possibly screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume Article & Quantity are in column A and Column B, Code and Article are in columns E & F, Code and Quantity are in columns I & J.

Add a VLOOKUP formula in column G

```
=VLOOKUP(F2,$A$2:$B$4,2,FALSE)
```

and fill down.
in column J (this is is the answer column) add a SUMIF Formula:

```
=SUMIF($E$2:$E$7,I2,$G$2:$G$7)
```

and fill down

(your row numbers in the formulas will be different)